use xcom shared variable as key in BigQueryInsertJobOperator configuration
I am having a case where I want to share a string to a BigQueryInsertJobOperator and use it as a key to take a given configuration. I try to do it as is:
Inside dag definition I am using PythonOperator to push a variable to xcom:
def capture_mode(**context):
    trigger = context["dag_run"].conf["message"].strip()
    mode = "case_a" if (trigger == "trigger_casea") else "case_b"
    task_instance = context["task_instance"]
    task_instance.xcom_push(key="mode", value=mode)
    return mode

capture_mode = PythonOperator(
    task_id="capture_mode",
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=capture_mode,
    dag=dag,
)

Afterwards I try to pull the parameter mode to use it as a parameter key for a json configuration:
copy_data = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
    task_id="copy-table",
    configuration={
        "copy": {
            "sourceTable": {
                "projectId": copy_data_config["sourceTable"]["projectId"],
                "datasetId": copy_data_config["sourceTable"]["datasetId"],
                "tableId": copy_data_config["sourceTable"]["tableId"][
                    "{{task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='capture_mode', key='mode')}}"
                ],
            },
            "destinationTable": {
                "projectId": copy_data_config["destinationTable"]["projectId"],
                "datasetId": copy_data_config["destinationTable"]["datasetId"],
                "tableId": copy_data_config["destinationTable"]["tableId"][
                    "{{task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='capture_mode', key='mode')}}"
                ],
            },
            "createDisposition": "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
            "writeDisposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
            "useLegacySql": False,
            "priority": "BATCH",
        }
    },
    impersonation_chain=config["serviceAccountName"],
    location=config["datasetsLocation"],
)

the json configuration looks like this:
  "copy_data": {
  "sourceTable": {
    "projectId": "project_id",
    "datasetId": "dataset_id",
    "tableId": {
      "case_a": "table_a",
      "case_b": "table_b"
    }
  }

Here I am trying to pull the right value in order to get case_a or case_b configuration.:
  {{task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='capture_mode', key='mode')}}

But I am getting the following error KeyError in the lines referencing the line above:
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
   File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/my_dag.py", line 139, in <module>
   "tableId": copy_data_config["sourceTable"]["tableId"][
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    KeyError: "{{task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='capture_mode', key='mode')}}"

What am I doing wrong ?

could you share copy_data_config declaration?

The reason for the error is because {{task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='capture_mode', key='mode')}} is the key use for dictionary access in copy_data_config["sourceTable"]["tableId"] and an entry with this key doesn't exist in the dictionary.
Template values are interpolated when the TaskInstance is executed.
Since you need the value of the xcom variable to be looked up in the copy_data_config, you can set the dictionary as a param.
copy_data = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
    task_id="copy-table",
    configuration={
        "copy": {
            "sourceTable": {
                "projectId": copy_data_config["sourceTable"]["projectId"],
                "datasetId": copy_data_config["sourceTable"]["datasetId"],
                "tableId": "{{params.sourceTableId.get(task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='capture_mode', key='mode'))}}"
,
            },
            "destinationTable": {
                "projectId": copy_data_config["destinationTable"]["projectId"],
                "datasetId": copy_data_config["destinationTable"]["datasetId"],
                "tableId": "{{params.destinationTableId.get(task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='capture_mode', key='mode'))}}"
                ,
            },
            "createDisposition": "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
            "writeDisposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
            "useLegacySql": False,
            "priority": "BATCH",
        }
    },
    params={
        "sourceTableId": copy_data_config["sourceTable"]["tableId"],
        "destinationTableId": copy_data_config["destinationTable"]["tableId"]  
    },
    impersonation_chain=config["serviceAccountName"],
    location=config["datasetsLocation"],
)

tableId in the configuration field should interpolated correctly with this modification because the configuration field is a template field.
Actually, I think the Xcom approach is expensive for your objective because the function pushing the value is based on values available in the context of the task instance.
A custom template user defined macro will simplify the implementation and save on the storage employed for the xcom variable.
def get_mode(message):
    trigger = message.strip()
    return "case_a" if (trigger == "trigger_casea") else "case_b"

copy_data = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
    task_id="copy-table",
    configuration={
        "copy": {
            "sourceTable": {
                "projectId": copy_data_config["sourceTable"]["projectId"],
                "datasetId": copy_data_config["sourceTable"]["datasetId"],
                "tableId": "{{params.sourceTableId.get(get_mode(dag_run.conf.get('message')))}}"
,
            },
            "destinationTable": {
                "projectId": copy_data_config["destinationTable"]["projectId"],
                "datasetId": copy_data_config["destinationTable"]["datasetId"],
                "tableId": "{{params.destinationTable.get(get_mode(dag_run.conf.get('message')))}}"
                ,
            },
            "createDisposition": "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
            "writeDisposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
            "useLegacySql": False,
            "priority": "BATCH",
        }
    },
    user_defined_macros={"get_mode": get_mode},
    params={
        "sourceTableId": copy_data_config["sourceTable"]["tableId"],
        "destinationTableId": copy_data_config["destinationTable"]["tableId"]  
    },
    impersonation_chain=config["serviceAccountName"],
    location=config["datasetsLocation"],
)

